# SQL/LINQ vs. Dados para alimentar gráfico

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

Estou tentando gerar uma consulta no VS2015 com Linq (aqui, exemplifiquei em SQL, para agilizar até meus testes direto no banco) que retorne os dados agrupados e contados de 6 meses atrás, acontece que em alguns do meses não há dados logo ele não aparece no resultado.

**O que recebo:**

`total | data
 2      06/2017
 4      08/2017
 18     11/2017`

**Como esperado:**

`total | data
 2      06/2017
 0      07/2017
 4      08/2017
 0      09/2017
 0      10/2017
 18     11/2017`

**Minha query**

```
    SELECT COUNT(Curso.ID_VENDA) as total, FORMAT(MAX(Venda.DATA),'MM/yyyy') AS data 
    FROM Curso 
    INNER JOIN Venda ON Curso.ID_VENDA = Venda.ID_VENDA
    INNER JOIN Produto ON Curso.ID_PRODUTO = Produto.ID_PRODUTO
    WHERE Produto.ID_CATEGORIA = 8
    AND Venda.DATA > dateadd(m, -6, getdate() - datepart(d, getdate()) + 1) 
    GROUP BY (YEAR(Venda.DATA) * 100) + MONTH(Venda.DATA)
    ORDER BY MAX(Venda.DATA) ASC
```

Alguém já passou por caso similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie uma tabela temporária com todos os meses para fazer JOIN. Segue o exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE #TB_DATAS(Data   varchar(10))

INSERT INTO #TB_DATAS (Data) VALUES ('06/2017')
INSERT INTO #TB_DATAS (Data) VALUES ('07/2017')
INSERT INTO #TB_DATAS (Data) VALUES ('08/2017')
INSERT INTO #TB_DATAS (Data) VALUES ('09/2017')
INSERT INTO #TB_DATAS (Data) VALUES ('10/2017')
INSERT INTO #TB_DATAS (Data) VALUES ('11/2017')
```

E inclua essa tabela no JOIN

```
    SELECT COUNT(Curso.ID_VENDA) as total,  FORMAT(MAX(Venda.DATA), 'MM/yyyy') AS data , #TB_DATAS.Data as data2
FROM Curso 
INNER JOIN Venda ON Curso.ID_VENDA = Venda.ID_VENDA
INNER JOIN Produto ON Curso.ID_PRODUTO = Produto.ID_PRODUTO
RIGHT JOIN #TB_DATAS ON FORMAT(Venda.DATA,'MM/yyyy') = #TB_DATAS.Data
WHERE Produto.ID_CATEGORIA = 8
AND ((Venda.DATA > dateadd(m, -6, getdate() - datepart(d, getdate()) + 1) ) OR (Venda.DATA  is NULL))
GROUP BY (YEAR(Venda.DATA) * 100) + MONTH(Venda.DATA), #TB_Datas.Data
ORDER BY MAX(Venda.DATA) ASC
```

Comment: Humm, entendi a ideia!
Porém, ao tentar aplicar a solução proposta, recebi o seguinte erro:

Msg 1015, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
An aggregate cannot appear in an ON clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: Tem razão vou ajustar a query, não tinha reparado no group by, mas a ideia é essa

Comment: Fiz um ajuste retirando o Max do join, veja se assim resolve

Comment: Testei, mas infelizmente, ainda produz o mesmo resultado inicial.

Comment: Ajustei o nome da tabela temporária no join que estava errado

Comment: Fiz outros ajustes e testei, funcionou aqui

Comment: Alexandre, obrigado pela a ajuda.
De fato não consegui obter o mesmo resultado que o seu teste. Porém, sua linha de raciocínio me deu a ideia de resolver de uma forma diferente pelo C#.
Crio uma lista com os meses dentro do C#, executo a query e cruzo os dados para deixar no formato que o gráfico aceita.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente não retorna os valores zerados porque você está tentando puxar cursos que não existem (pois o *count* está zerado) use RIGHT JOIN e provavelmente funcionará.

```
SELECT COUNT(Curso.ID_VENDA) as total, FORMAT(MAX(Venda.DATA),'MM/yyyy') AS data 
FROM Curso 

RIGHT JOIN Produto ON Curso.ID_PRODUTO = Produto.ID_PRODUTO
RIGHT JOIN Venda ON Curso.ID_VENDA = Venda.ID_VENDA

WHERE Produto.ID_CATEGORIA = 8
AND Venda.DATA > dateadd(m, -6, getdate() - datepart(d, getdate()) + 1) 
GROUP BY (YEAR(Venda.DATA) * 100) + MONTH(Venda.DATA)
ORDER BY MAX(Venda.DATA) ASC
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado, mas havia tentado isso. Produz o mesmo resultado inicial.